# Use case for private components

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I'm trying to come up with a simple use case for private components and here it it. Suppose I have the module `HelloWorldAppModule` with one public and one private component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    template: `
    <div>
        <private></private>
    </div>`
})
class HelloWorldComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'private',
    template: `<span>I am private</span>`
})
class PrivateComponent {
}


@NgModule({
    declarations: [HelloWorldComponent, PrivateComponent],
    exports: [HelloWorldComponent]
})
class HelloWorldAppModule {
}
```

As you can see, this module exports only `HelloWorldComponent`, however, inside the template of `HelloWorldComponent` the `PrivateComponent` is used. This should work fine, since both components are registered in `declarations`.

Then, I create another module `UsesHelloWorldModule` that imports `HelloWorldAppModule` and so, as I understand, I can use components exported by it in templates of directives registered within `HelloWorldAppModule`. So here it is:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'uses-hello-world',
    template: `<hello-world></hello-world><private></private>`
})
class UsesHelloWorldComponent {
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [HelloWorldAppModule],
    declarations: [UsesHelloWorldComponent],
})
class UsesHelloWorldModule {
}
```

However, I also used `<private>` component from the `HelloWorldAppModule` that was not exported. So what's going to happen? Am I right that angular is going to throw an error when parsing the `<private></private>` tag?

**EDIT:**

Also, what will happen if only  is used inside `UsesHelloWorldComponent`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'uses-hello-world',
    template: `<hello-world></hello-world>`
})
class UsesHelloWorldComponent {
}
```

Please note that it uses `<private>` inside its template.

Appreciate any comments as there is not much examples of private components on the web.

Comment: Yes it should throw an exception with component not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<private></private>` should cause an error about missing `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`. If you proveded `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to be able to use custom tags that are not Angular components, then you won't get an error, unless you also add bindings like `<private [prop]="value">` - which will cause an error because `<private>` won't have a `prop` property when it's not a `PrivateComponent`

Comment: thanks, and if I don't use `<private></private>` inside `UsesHelloWorldComponent` template, the `<hello-world></hello-world>` component will still be rendered with `<private></private>` inside its template without an error, correct?

Comment: Yes, but only as custom HTML element, not an Angular component (I hope I correctly understand your comment)

Comment: Probably I didn't state the question clearly. If you look at `UsesHelloWorldComponent` template, you can see that `<hello-world>` is used inside of it. This should work fine, because `HelloWorldAppModule` exports `HelloWorldComponent`. However, inside of `<hello-world>` the `<private>` component is used, which is not exported. What's going to happen then? I edited the question to show that

Comment: I still have troubles to get your point. If it is used inside `<hello-world>` then a component will be generated of the `<private></private>` element, no matter where you use an exported component (inside or outside of the module where it's declared), its content will always be the same.

Comment: Thanks, so basically, the components defined in a module and not exported **can only be used in templates** of components that are defined in this module, correct?

Comment: appreciate, just wondering if there is any difference with [dynamically created components](http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/)

Comment: I'm quite sure it's the same.